# Summarise(across(where)) in R

Tags: r, summarize, across

I have the following data file called "data_2":

```
Person Weight Height
A      55     155
B      65     165
C      75     175
```

I wanna use the Summarise(across(where))-command in order to generate the total weight and the weight for each person. This is what I have tried until now.

```
data_2 <- read_excel("data_2.xlsx", sheet = 2)


data_2 %>%
summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

Unfortunately, this don't work correctly. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Expected output:

```
Person Weight 
A      55     
B      65     
C      75
Total  195
```

Comment: Maybe this? `data_2 %>% group_by(Person) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))`

Comment: That will generate the height column as well. Also, I don't get the total weight.

Comment: Do you need a new column with total weight that is 195? Can you share your expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question so that you could see the expected output now.

Comment: `df[1:2] %>% janitor::adorn_totals()`

Comment: well, there was no solution the Summarise(across(where))" there. So I don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Summarise(across(where))` when you want to summarise only `Weight` variable? `across` is used to apply same function to multiple columns. You are applying a function to only one column here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- data_2 %>%
  bind_rows(data_2 %>% select(-1) %>%
              summarise_all(sum) %>% mutate(Person='Total'))
```

Output:

```
  Person Weight Height
1      A     55    155
2      B     65    165
3      C     75    175
4  Total    195    495
```

Or using your code:

```
#Code 2
newdf <- data_2 %>% 
  bind_rows(data_2 %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric),sum)) %>%
              mutate(Person='Total')) %>% select(-Height)
```

Output:

```
  Person Weight
1      A     55
2      B     65
3      C     75
4  Total    195
```

Comment: But I don't want to print the Height column. Only Weight.

Comment: @JohnDoe Check the last code in the solution!

Comment: @JohnDoe Or try `newdf <- data_2 %>% select(-Height) %>%
  bind_rows(data_2 %>% summarise(across(starts_with('Weight'),sum)) %>%
              mutate(Person='Total'))
`

Comment: That solution works, however if I have a longer file with says N persons, it will only show the 10 first persons (Person A -J)  s tibble. It will generate a 15 x 1 tibble but only the 10 first are visible. How can I show the other observations as well(Person K - N, + Total)?

Comment: @JohnDoe In the new dataframe it will be all persons you have. If you want to print on console all people try this `data_2 %>% select(-Height) %>%
  bind_rows(data_2 %>% summarise(across(starts_with('Weight'),sum)) %>%
              mutate(Person='Total')) %>% data.frame()`

Comment: '''newdf <- data_2 %>% bind_rows(my_data_2 %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric),sum)) %>% mutate(Person='Total')) %>% select(-Height)'''

Comment: I wanna use that command since it uses the summarise(across(where)). Not the other one you suggested.

Comment: @JohnDoe In that case try `newdf <- data_2 %>% bind_rows(data_2 %>%
                                summarise(across(where(is.numeric),sum)) %>%
                                mutate(Person='Total')) %>% select(-Height) %>%
  data.frame()
`

Comment: Now it works perfectly fine. I will accept your answer. Thank you for taking the time! :)

Comment: @JohnDoe Many thanks John :) are you still learning R (new user)?

Comment: Yes, I do. I think it's a bit hard but I progress every day.

Comment: @JohnDoe I understand. I use to teach customized session for specific problems with R Programming. If you can be interested at any point of time, let me know :)